# Display custID for customers who ordered the exact book > 1

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

The goal is to find customers who ordered the same book > 1 on an order. For example:

```
order_id |order_line |book_id | quantity | order_price
--------- ----------- -------- --------- -----------
33034      1           1619      10         $35
33034      2           1619       5         $16
```

Is this correct?

```
SELECT distinct cust_id
    ,(SELECT cust_name_last
      FROM bkorders.customers AS CS
      WHERE CS.cust_id = OH.cust_id) AS cust_name_last
FROM bkorders.order_headers AS OH
WHERE EXISTS
    (SELECT 1
     FROM bkorders.order_details AS OD
     WHERE order_id > 1
     AND OD.order_id = OH.order_id
     HAVING COUNT(distinct order_line) > 1)
```

I have attached a screenshot of the three tables I am using.
[image]

Edit: We are only to use subqueries for this task

Comment: What is the quantity column in order_details table for?

Comment: Quantity column shows how many of that book they purchased.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT distinct cust_id
    ,(SELECT cust_name_last
      FROM bkorders.customers AS CS
      WHERE CS.cust_id = OH.cust_id) AS cust_name_last
FROM bkorders.order_headers AS OH
WHERE EXISTS
    (SELECT 1 FROM bkorders.order_details OD
    WHERE OD.order_id = OH.order_id
    GROUP BY order_id, book_id HAVING count(*)>1)
```

Comment: I apologize! i should have made it clear that we are only use to subqueries.

Comment: no worries, I edited to use only correlated queries. This should return the customers that have at least one order with the same book_id in at least two lines.